# How to display multiple selectable images in one JScrollPane?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlist

I started to build this by creating a JLabel for each image and add it to the pane. This worked but I need to be able to 'select' an image to display the image name and resolution, as well as be able to delete the selected image and add images to the pane.

Would a JList be the route to go here?

Thank you!

Comment: `"Would a JList be the route to go here?"` -- yes. Simply add ImageIcons to the JList's model, and bingo, you're done.

Comment: Why can you make an try on it, instead of asking @user2907236?

Comment: @Hariharan Because I've already wasted hours making a try on the 'JLabel for each image' method. Also I thought this may save someone else the hassle in the future :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you very much, that's what I wanted to hear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Would a JList be the route to go here?"` -- yes. Simply add ImageIcons to the JList's model, and bingo, you're done.